# Show that $\psi$ is surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gaussian-integers

I have read a lot answers about this (for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23358/quotient-ring-of-gaussian-integers), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507534/prove-that-mathbbzi-langle-1i-rangle-cong-mathbbz-2-mathbbz), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157059/proving-mathbbzi-75i-cong-mathbbz-74)), but I want to prove this directly consider the canonical homomorphism, defined by,
\begin{align*}
 \psi : \mathbb{Z} &\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[i]/ I \\   
 x &\mapsto \psi(x):= x+I
\end{align*}
where $I=\langle a+bi\rangle$ and $(a,b)=1$, but I need to show $\psi$ is surjective, 'cause I'm able to show that if $\psi$ is surjective then $\ker \psi=\langle a^2+b^2\rangle$, and for the first isomorphism theorem it follows that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle a+bi\rangle\cong \mathbb{Z}_{a^2+b^2}$. In one of this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23358/quotient-ring-of-gaussian-integers/23379#23379) Matt E give and hint but I don't understand how finite works here. Any hint to show $\psi$ is surjective? Thank you guys. I think it's enough to show that there exists a $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\psi(m)=m+I=i+I$, 'cause then given $c+di+I\in\mathbb{Z}[i]/I$ then with $x:=c+dm\in\mathbb{Z}$ it's such that $\psi(x)=x+I=c+dm+I=c+di+I$. But how to show that $i\in \text{Im }\psi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $m+I = i+I$ for some $m\in\mathbb Z$ it suffices to show that $m-i\in I$ or, taking $m$ for $-m$, that $m+i\in I$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Choose $r, s\in\mathbb Z$ such that $ar+bs=1$; then
$$(a+bi)s + (a+bi)ri = (as-br) + (ar+bs)i = (as-br)+i\in I.$$
Take $m = as-br$.