# A question about Gauss integer

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, integers

The question is about the proof that  ${\mathbb{Z}\left[ i \right] /(i+2)}$  is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} /p\mathbb{Z}$.

To prove this problem,We restrict homomorphism $R \to R/I$ to $\mathbb{Z} \to R/I$ in order to show that image of R is the same as image of $\mathbb{Z}$.

I know the kernel of the restricted hom is $5\mathbb{Z}$  but I don't understand why the image of the restricted hom is $\mathbb{Z} /5\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}/I$?

I was confused by the mod $(a+bi)$ and $p\mathbb{Z}$ in the proof.

Comment: I guess you mean $p=2$.

Comment: See also the answers at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564077/mathbbzi-abi-cong-mathbbz-a2b2-if-a-b-1?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507534/prove-that-mathbbzi-langle-1i-rangle-cong-mathbbz-2-mathbbz?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @Wuestenfux I guess you mean $p=5$...

Comment: Thank you, I should read the textbook first.